# Destructure and retrieve the fully structured variable in one expression

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Is it possible to both destructure a variable and have access to the structured variable in the same call?

For example, what could I replace `???` below to get the desired output (and how else might I have to edit my code)

```
const foo = ({ a, b }) => {
  console.log(a) // 1
  console.log(b) // 2
  console.log(???) // { a: 1, b: 2 }
}
const x = { a: 1, b: 2 }
foo(x)
```

My goal is knowledge and succinct code - I want to avoid `const { a, b } = params` as the first line of `foo()` in the case where I might need to pass the entire params object on.

Comment: So `console.log({ a, b });` is not what you’re looking for?

Comment: @SebastianSimon agreed, the linked question in the question you linked answers this one - my early morning googling skills are poor lol, I'll vote to close as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

If the first argument is an object whose reference you want, it's not possible - once you destructure an argument, there's no longer any way to reference to the full argument, only some of its properties.

It *would* be possible if the object and parts you wanted was part of a larger object, though, because then you can reference the property name alone (to get the object into a variable), and then reference it again to destructure, eg:

```js
const foo = ({ obj: { a, b }, obj }) => {
  console.log(a) // 1
  console.log(b) // 2
  console.log(obj) // { a: 1, b: 2 }
}
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }
foo({ obj })
```

Your original code could work to an extent if the object had a property that referenced itself, but that's pretty weird:

```js
const foo = ({ a, b, obj }) => {
  console.log(a) // 1
  console.log(b) // 2
  console.log(obj) // { a: 1, b: 2 }
}
const x = { a: 1, b: 2 }
x.obj = x;
foo(x)
```

Comment: Then I'd replace the commonly expected `vals = { a, b } = params` with the somewhat unexpected `x.obj = x;` !